# Get CSV data from 60 URLs and append one after other Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have 60 URLs, each gives a CSV file and the data is new every day. What I want to accomplish is to create a VBA script which will use all the 60 URLs and get data and append 1 after other in same worksheet of excel. After that I want to refresh it daily ?

I have started doing it by recording macro but it doesn't give me a loop. Any help is appreciated, I'm new to VBA.

Comment: you should add your code to the question.

Comment: Why append them in Excel? Just append the actual .csv files themselves and open the *resulting file* in Excel.

Comment: Need to see the code you have tried so far. Also, does each csv have a row of headers to include/exclude?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

- prepare objects

  ```
  Dim wbTmp as Workbook
  Dim myWb as workbook
  Dim myRng as Range
  Dim rngTmp as Range

  Set myWb = ActiveWorkbook
  myWb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
  Set myRng = myWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1)
  ```
- Save the URLs in an Array

  ```
  Dim myURLs(1 To 60) as Variant
  myURLs(1) = "someurl"
  ...
  myURLs(60) = "lasturl"
  ```
- Loop through the Array

  ```
  Dim myURL as Variant
  For Each myURL in myURLs
      ... 'next point fills the loop
  ```
- Open each CSV as Workbbook (one after another)

  ```
      Set wbTmp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myURL)
      'OK, thats not for sure - I dont know how to open files from internet :)
      'Thats your part
  ```
- Copy the Used Range to your Main Workbook

  ```
      Set rngTmp = wbTmp.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
      Call rngTmp.Copy(Destination:=myRng)
      Set myRng = myRng.Offset(rngTmp.Rows.Count)

      Call wbTmp.Close(savechanges:=False)
  ```
- End the loop, kill objects

  ```
  Next myURL

  Set wbTmp = Nothing
  Set myWb = Nothing
  Set myRng = Nothing
  Set rngTmp = Nothing
  ```

Comment: This doesn't append the data to the same worksheet, it copies the worksheet into the main workbook so OP will end up with 60 sheets (assuming none of the sheet names clash) in the workbook.

Comment: You are right... I have to read more carefully :) I will delete this answer as soon as I am on my notebook again (sent from my mobile)

Comment: Or edit the answer - the looping through the URLs is still fine.

Comment: Ok, it should fit now. Is there something like a spoiler-tag to hide large codeblocks? I would use it to write the complete (copyable) code at the and of the answer.

Comment: No spoiler-tag exists. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292199/4243498) for a discussion. Your answer looks fine to me - broken into manageable chunks with a description for each one.